# Query to get all companies that have products with all specified attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

Let's say I have two tables (1 to many): table company with fk id and table product with fk id and also fields sId and tId (if sId has data tId is null and vice versa, not sure if it matters).

I want every company that has products with, for example sId=1, sId=2, tId=3 and tId=4.

So for a company to be eligible it has to have products with sId=1 and sId=2 and tId=3 and tId=4. If one is missing it shouldnt appear.

I tried joining the tables and doing

```
where pro.sId in ('1', '2') 
and pro.tId in ('3','4')
```

But it doesn't give me any companies. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us a sample data? Also the expected output.

Comment: the statements appears conflicting `if sId has data tId is null and vice versa` and `to be eligible it has to have products with sId=1 and sId=2 and tId=3 and tId=4`

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. One is:

```
select * from company where id in
(
  select company_id from product where sid = 1
  intersect
  select company_id from product where sid = 2
  intersect
  select company_id from product where tid = 3
  intersect
  select company_id from product where tid = 4
);
```

Another:

```
select * from company
where id in (select company_id from product where sid = 1)
  and id in (select company_id from product where sid = 2)
  and id in (select company_id from product where tid = 3)
  and id in (select company_id from product where tid = 4);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use aggregation. Assuming no duplicate `sld` or `tld` per `company_id` in the `products` table:

```
select c.id
from companies c
inner join products p on p.company_id = c.id
where p.sld in (1, 2) or p.tld in (3, 4)
group by c.id
having count(*) = 4
```

If there are duplicates, you can change the having clause to:

```
having count(distinct p.sld) = 2 and count(distinct p.tld) = 2
```